# HTTP 408 response code through ELB after using explicit ciphers ( HTTP 200 when hitting the instance directly throught the private IP)

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, ecdhe

Recently, I have been taking on a task to update ssl ciphers to use strong suites and for the recommended fix, i updated `server.ssl.ciphers` to have four ciphers. This app is deployed on aws ec2 with classic load balancer. The load balancer has proper listerners with custom listener set to listen on the provided port and use those four ciphers that I have explicitly provided on the applciation as well. However, When i try to hit the alb's r53 domain, i get a 408 resopnse code. If i get the private IP from the console and hit the ip in the same port, i get a 200 response code. Can someone help on this?
Thanks in advance.

Tried configuring the listeners but havent found the combination that would work.